# I'd like to ask how much the class is. And I'd like to know if I can say like these

Tags: word-usage

I'm thinking of taking a class to practice English. It is not for free and the cost is in my interest. As I'm just a student, I don't enough money to take a class that demands me high cost. So, I'm going to call the academy and ask like this:

> 1. I'd like to ask how much it is that I take the class.
> 2. I'd like to ask how much the class is.
> 3. I'd like to ask how much money the class takes me.

Comment: Please clarify: You have to pay to participate? Taking the class costs money? Right?

Comment: Sorry for that. I added some more details

Comment: If I were you, I'll ask it this way, "How much is the enrollment fee [for this class]?" In case the payment for the class is on a per-session basis [some online schools do], you may ask, "How much is the fee per session [for this class]?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much is *X*?

Your version 2 uses the typical phrase to inquire about the cost of something.

Version 3 doesn't make sense because it's never *the class* that takes money (neither real -> it's the school, nor figuratively speaking -> an abstract 'it' takes the money)

Version 1 *could* be used but is rather cumbersome. I would advise against it.